# Haskell: folding over a map, while updating a secondary map

Tags: haskell

Consider the following map: `Map.fromList [(1,"foo"), (2,"bar"), (3,"foo")]`

I'd like to produce: `Map.fromList [(1,"foo"), (2,"bar"), (3,"1")]`. The last key, 3, previously associated with "foo", is now associated with "1" - so by following this value (and converting the string into a number) I can still arrive at "foo". If the result was `Map.fromList [(1,"3"), (2,"bar"), (3,"foo")]`, it would also be OK.

Ideally I'd implement that by folding over the original map. Along with it, I'd incrementally populate a secondary (reverse) map with the elements ("foo", 1), ("bar", 2), etc. If the current key is found in the secondary map, instead of inserting it into the final map, I'd insert its associated value.

Is there a simple/elegant way to sequence that, without multiple passes or a Monad?

```
main = do
     let names = Map.fromList [(1,"foo"), (2,"bar"), (3,"foo")]
         link acc k v = -- insert into map1, depending map2's lookup
         names' = Map.foldlWithKey link (Map.empty, Map.empty) names
     putStrLn $ show names'
```

Comment: This seems very strange. It would seem slightly less strange if you wanted to produce, say, `Map Integer (Either Integer String)`, making it explicit whether the value is the final one or a reference. But even with that change, it's a bit odd. Why do you need this?

Comment: Indeed... This is an adaptation of my actual case, a minimum example I could come up with to show the essence of my doubt: updating a secondary data-structure while mapping/folding over a map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best you can do is using [`mapAccumWithKey`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:mapAccumWithKey). Then, something like this:

```
deduplicate :: Map Int String -> Map Int String
deduplicate = snd . Map.mapAccumWithKey go Map.empty
  where
    go accum k v = case Map.lookup v accum of
                    Nothing -> (Map.insert v (show k) accum, v)
                    Just v' -> (accum, v')
```

This maps the keys one by one while threading through a `Map String String` which keeps track of values already seen and their corresponding keys. There is obviously some cooler stuff to be done if you want to try something parallel, but sequentially this is optimal - it should be `O(n log n)` and you need at least that to detect shared keys in the first place.

---

With `names' = deduplicate names`, I get the output `fromList [(1,"foo"),(2,"bar"),(3,"1")]`.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of mapAccumWithKey.